# Bing Maps WPF user control in Windows Forms app - map appears broken

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, bing-maps

I have followed [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65450109/how-can-i-add-a-bing-maps-component-to-my-c-sharp-winforms-app/65464892) to integrate a Bing Maps WPF control into my Windows Forms app. But when I start the application and view the map, it appears broken like in [this image](https://ibb.co/JcyV0g3).

Zooming in and out does not help, the map tiles do not fit together.

Here is the XAML of my WPF user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="My.Views.BingMapsUControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:My.Views"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <maps:Map x:Name="mapControl" Center="48.21,16.37" ZoomLevel="12" Grid.Row="0"
              CredentialsProvider="xxx">
        </maps:Map>
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" Grid.Row="1"></ListBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly load a WPF control in a WinForm app. Follow this blog post: https://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2012/01/05/using-bing-maps-in-winforms/

Comment: That is exactly the way I did it!